# How to modify domain in AWS Amplify with rewrite rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

How can I rewrite a URL in AWS Amplify from:

```
https://a.example.com/path
```

to:

```
https://a.b.example.com/path
```

Given that the domain `example.com` is variable because the Amplify app uses multiple domains.

That means that the same rule should rewrite from:

```
https://a.example2.org/path
```

to:

```
https://a.b.example2.org/path
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Amplify's Rewrites and redirects and write your own regex rule. This is explained in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html)

Comment: I saw that, but couldn’t figure out how to wrote the rule for the example above.